# Finding a nested document and updating it accordingly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

Updated the method a little, still does not work but I think I am on the right path...

```
const condition = { 'assets._id': assetId };
    const updateData = {
      assetName: editAssetData.assetName,
      assetQuantity: editAssetData.assetQuantity,
      singleQuantityPrice: editAssetData.singleQuantityPrice,
      totalQuantityPrice: editAssetData.totalQuantityPrice,
    };
    const options = { new: true };

    const newAsset = await Catalog.findOneAndUpdate(condition, { $set: updateData }, options).exec();
```

I'm trying to create a route for updating single documents.

Here is the catalogModel, I want to update a respective asset based on the assetId I receive...

```js
const catalogSchema = new Schema({
  assetType: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  assets: [{
    assetName: { type: String, required: false },
    assetQuantity: { type: Number, required: false },
    singleQuantityPrice: { type: Number, required: false },
    totalQuantityPrice: { type: Number, required: false },
  }],
});
```

This is what my editAssetData object looks like:

```js
{
  assetName: 'goldis',
  assetQuantity: '1',
  singleQuantityPrice: '1',
  totalQuantityPrice: '1'
}
```

This is my query, which does not work. I've tried other methods and instead of updating a single row it replaced all documents within assets with editassetData.

```js
 const {
    assetId,
    editAssetData,
  } = req.body;

    const newAsset = await Catalog.updateOne(
      { 'assets._id': assetId },
      {
        $set: {
          assetName: editAssetData.assetName,
          assetQuantity: editAssetData.assetQuantity,
          singleQuantityPrice: editAssetData.singleQuantityPrice,
          totalQuantityPrice: editAssetData.totalQuantityPrice,
        },
      },
    );

    const asset = await newAsset.save();
```

The response I get is: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }... meaning nothing was found and modified.

I've tried seeing whether my condition finds anything and it does not. I don't understand why not though...

This is what a document looks like for example:

```js
_id: 'the catalog object id'
assetType: "gold"
description: "test gold assets"
creator: 'the user object id'
assets: [{ _id: 'the asset object id', assetName: "goldisnice", assetQuantity: 1, singleQuantityPrice: 1200, totalQuantityPrice: 1200  }]
```

Comment: Can your requirement be written in pure Mongo DB query?

Comment: @Mallik Yes it could

Comment: @Gabriel have you tried `{ 'assets._id': mongoose.types.ObjectId(assetId) }` ?

Comment: @mickl Yes I've tried that as well

Comment: @Gabriel, I have added a mongo DB query in the answer section. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MongoDB query run from mongo shell on windows10
//sample data for catalog Schema collection
> db.catalogSchema.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5791b0636fe5b2e945cd48"),
        "assetType" : "Mouse",
        "description" : "Logitech Mouse 120v with laser",
        "creator" : "johnd",
        "assets" : [
                {
                        "assetName" : "logitech1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 12,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 100,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 1200
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "microsoft1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 15,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 200,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 3000
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "goldis",
                        "assetQuantity" : "11",
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : "1",
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : "1"
                }
        ]
}
//update , need to use $ to access array elements
> db.catalogSchema.updateOne(      {"assets.assetName":"goldis"},      {$set:{"assets.$.assetQuantity":"22"}}      );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.catalogSchema.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5791b0636fe5b2e945cd48"),
        "assetType" : "Mouse",
        "description" : "Logitech Mouse 120v with laser",
        "creator" : "johnd",
        "assets" : [
                {
                        "assetName" : "logitech1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 12,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 100,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 1200
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "microsoft1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 15,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 200,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 3000
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "goldis",
                        "assetQuantity" : "22",
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : "1",
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : "1"
                }
        ]
}
//update , need to use $ to access array elements(another collection field as example)
> db.catalogSchema.updateOne(      {"assets.assetName":"goldis"},      {$set:{"assets.$.assetName":"goldis New"}}      );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.catalogSchema.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5791b0636fe5b2e945cd48"),
        "assetType" : "Mouse",
        "description" : "Logitech Mouse 120v with laser",
        "creator" : "johnd",
        "assets" : [
                {
                        "assetName" : "logitech1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 12,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 100,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 1200
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "microsoft1",
                        "assetQuantity" : 15,
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : 200,
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : 3000
                },
                {
                        "assetName" : "goldis New",
                        "assetQuantity" : "22",
                        "singleQuantityPrice" : "1",
                        "totalQuantityPrice" : "1"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try your method but I don'T really see the difference between yours and mine. I updated my method a little and it looks like this now:... I've updated my post